# Best practice to share WebForm application with the new upgraded Blazor server app on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor

I'm new to the ways of cloud computing.  I have an existing website (e.g. [www.old.com](http://www.old.com)) that is in production and that has been moved to the Azure cloud.  The old site implements Features A, B, and C and is running fine.

I am developing a new application for [www.old.com](http://www.old.com)) using Blaor server.  The new app is an upgrade in technology to the old site but will eventually implement the same feaures A,B,and C.

My question:  What's a best practice for setting this up in the cloud that will allow me to keep the old site running but point the user to the new site when a feature is complete and ready to be viewed?  In other words, when Feature A is avilable in the new site, can I have the user navigate to the new site for that one web page and then navigate back to the old site?

I have not tried to implement this in the cloud yet.  Looking for direction onthe best practice.

Comment: Is your old application .NetCore? If so, you can run Blazor and Server-Side on the same site, and navigate between them.  If your old app is well structured you can share the same business logic and data pipeline. Here's an article that shows how to add Blazor to a standard .NetCore web application i.e. your current site - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: OP says the old website is Web Forms, i.e. aspx, not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Sometimes you miss the obvious. :-)

Comment: Thanks for input.  I will try the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reverse proxy to selectively serve different URLs from the old and new sites as you migrate. MS has a doc section on this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/inc/overview.